# How/when the 'after_filter' works/runs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, filter

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know (for *performance* reasons) whether or not the `after_filter` runs after that view files are rendered. That is, when an user access a my application URL, the related view file that he/she should display is rendered before that the `after_filter` runs or the `after_filter` runs before that the view file is rendered?

*In other words*, **the application *server* starts to send the rendered view data to the user before to run the `after_filter` or it waits to run the `after_filter` method and only then it sends that view data?**

*P.S.*: I opened this question because I would like to run some system updates (*note*: these updates doesn't affect the view output data and are not "used by"/"necessary to" the view at all) without impact on the end user experience (for example: slow loading of my application Web pages).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to be aware that a request to your server is fully consistent and runs in its own thread.

If you put code in an `after_filter`, this will delay the whole request: to sum up badly, if the thread is alive, the page is not delivered.

That's why you find great plugins like `DelayedJob` and `Resque`, they work in a parallel processes and won't affect your app.

---

To answer your original question , `after_filter` are triggered after the view has been processed.

This is sometimes a hassle that's why [people created some `before_render` filters.](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/ruby-on-rails-before-render-filter)

Answer (score 7):

`after_filter` is run after the content has been generated, but before it's been sent to the client. You can verify this is so because you have access to the completely-generated response data in the `response` method of your controller in any after_filter.

After_filters are inappropriate places to put long running tasks as they will definitely impact the users' experience. Consider instead using the after_filter to kick off a long running [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) task to perform your background work instead.