# execute code in rails after response is sent to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, garbage-collection

Using Rails 3.0.7, REE 1.8.7.

I want to run code (specifically, Garbage Collection) in Rails after the response has been sent to the browser.

Is there a way to patch into Rails/Rack/something so that I can call GC.start right after the response is sent to the browser from the controller?

*Note: This is not a situation where I want to use delayed_job or resque. I am aware of those tools already and they are not appropriate for this use case.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's options for tuning Ruby's garbage collector that don't involve having to patch Passenger. You might want to re-write the question to focus on that. Otherwise you'd just do it in `after_filter`.

Comment: We're already tuning GC, but would like to run it outside of the req/response cycle as well.

Comment: Also, putting it in after_filter would delay the response to the user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437315/how-when-the-after-filter-works-runs

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to hook into Rack to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This one-line patch to passenger allows you to run GC between requests](https://github.com/wbharding/passenger/commit/58dae4baf153de30dbfae5cf0e0c38bc653b366d).  After implementing it, we saw our GC execution time (as reported by NewRelic) drop by about 40%.  Individual results may vary. :)

Thanks to [this post](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/uncategorized/rails-3-performance-abysmal-to-good-to-great/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Merb but Rails itself doesn't allow you to do that. If all you need is call the garbage collector just start a new thread once the request is done and call the GC. This way you don't delay the response to the user and get what you want.

```
Thread.new do 
  GC.start
end
```

If you really need to do this, you should probably think about two things, creating less objects or running on **JRuby** that has a much better garbage collector running.

Comment: Can naive mark-and-sweep GC work in a separate thread?  Seems like the object space would be changing while it was trying to identify things for collection.

Comment: Tried this and my object space started growing much faster than normal, not sure if Ruby's GC can work properly in a separate thread.